# How to auto resize img group with browser change size?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to auto resize img group with browser change size?

I almost finish it in css, but now I can't set overflow:hidden let the 5th or 6th.. picture hide.

(img from php)
(I will connect jQuery plugin [scrolling-carousel](http://www.convergent-evolution.co.uk/resources/jquery-plugins/scrolling-carousel/).)

Any suggestion i'd really appreciate you taking the time.

Here is my http://jsfiddle.net/uSHbc/1/ 
HTML

```
<div class="conimgwrap2">
    <div class="conimgwrap">
        <div class="conimg">

            <div>
                <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg">
            </div>                
            <div>
                <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg">
            </div>                
            <div>
                <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/demo/2_s.jpg">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.conimgwrap2{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
.conimgwrap{
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
}

.conimg{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.conimg div{
    display: inline;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.conimg img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}​
```

Comment: You already done it. By setting 100% for max-height & max-width ,image will be resized with browser size.

Comment: But I can't find the way to hide the img overflow img group container.

Comment: if you want to hide overflow for that img group, 
put
    overflow:hidden;
inside
    .conimg img{}

Comment: actually do you want to hide that picture or set overflow to hidden?
The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an element's box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inner-

> display: inline;
>       max-width: _%;
>       max-height: 100%;

outer-

> white-space: nowrap;
>   and position set learn how from http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your point "I almost finish it in css, but now I can't set overflow:hidden let the 5th or 6th.. picture hide."

but if you want to re size the image with browser change size you can do it with following css.

.conimg img{ max-width: 100%; height: auto;}​

Thank you.

Comment: I can't find the way to hide some img overflow img group container.

Comment: I think you need to remove the "max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;" from "conimg" class and after that a fixed width and overflow:hidden will work

Comment: for this you need to resize the div with media query

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
.conimg div{
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 20%; /* (100% / the number of divs) */ 
}
.conimg img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 hack */
}​
```

This will create equally spaced divs (in your example 5 elements) inside your image container's parent and both images and their container's will scale up/down when window is resized.

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/buqqn/